# Elixir - Why are type specs required in a @callback definition?

Tags: types, module, elixir, behavior

It seems like when you define a behaviour you have to include type specs within the `@callback` definition. Then when you adopt the behaviour, the compiler requires that the `function_name/arity` is defined, but is perfectly happy if you don't follow the type specs.

My questions are:

1. Are those observations correct?
2. If yes, why does `@callback` couple type specs with the actual functionality of checking that the `function_name/arity` is defined? It makes it difficult to understand what is documentation and what is core functionality. The rest of Elixir seems to clearly separate the two, keeping type specs as an optional addition.

For example:

If we omit the type specs, we get a compile error

```
defmodule Greeting do
  @callback hello(person)
end
# (CompileError) iex:82: type specification missing return type: hello(person)
```

To make the compiler happy, we have to include type specs:

```
defmodule Greeting do
  @callback hello(%Person{}) :: {:ok, String.t} | {:error, String.t}
end
```

Now when we adopt the behaviour, the compiler checks that `function_name/arity` is defined:

```
defmodule WesternGreeting do
  @behaviour Greeting
  def hello(), do: "Howdy"
end
# warning: undefined behaviour function hello/1 (for behaviour Greeting)
```

However all the type specs in the @callback are disregarded by the compiler:

```
defmodule WesternGreeting2 do
  @behaviour Greeting
  def hello([a, b, c]), do: a <> b <> c
end
# No warnings or errors
```

Comment: Specs are not checked by the compiler, but by external tools like dialyzer

Comment: @Grych the error in his post says `# (CompileError) iex:82: type specification missing return type: hello(person)` That seems to suggest it's indeed checked by the compiler. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of erlang, it was not required. Somewhere along the line (I don't recall exactly when), it was realized that if you add them it then Dialyzer could do some additional validation.

In addition, you can actually get the types from a module at runtime which has some uses.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lT4_E6dooQ

Answer (score 0):

It's cause `@callback` is same as `@spec`, it expects types.
If you will define return type in first example, it will fail too:

```
iex(1)> defmodule Greeting do
...(1)>   @callback hello(person) :: any()
...(1)> end
** (CompileError) iex:2: type person() undefined
```

About checking types, I suppose it is not done yet